# Rails nested attributes children callbacks aren't fired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, nested-attributes

I'm running into a bizarre issue where children callbacks aren't fired when the parent is updated...

I have the following model setup:

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end
```

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :budget

  before_save :update_totals

  private
  def update_totals
    self.some_field = value
  end
end
```

In my form, I have the fields nested (built using `fields_for`):

```
= form_for @budget do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :line_items do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :amount
```

Why is the `update_totals` callback on the child never fired / what can I do to make it fire?

Comment: I built a small sample application and was unable to reproduce your issue. Are you certain that the callback is not being fired? The easiest way to make sure is to raise an exception inside the method. If the exception is being raised, then we know that the callback is being fired therefore maybe there's a flaw in the code of the callback, not the callback itself.

Comment: I'm positive. I didn't use exceptions, I use `puts` statements, but nothing is showing up in the development log

Comment: Hm even with ```puts``` I am still able to see the output in my own development log. There must be something else at work but I'd need to know a bit more about your application to see what the issue is.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: no ... :(. I ended up just writing a bunch of weird callbacks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had the same issue. `before_save` callback is not called when the model is not changed.

You're updating `line_items`, not the `budget`, so rails thinks that it is not updated and doesn't call `save` for it.

You need to change `before_save` to `after_validation` so it will be called even if model has no changed attributes. And when in this callback you change some attributes, rails will see that your model had changed and will call `save`.

Comment: Thanks, @Nico, removed that from answer. For some reason I thought that it should trigger callbacks

Comment: I do have the same problem with after_save , what should I do @Nico

Comment: Doesn't after_validation fire every time, even if validation fails? Whereas before_save only fires if validation passes?

Comment: @weexpectedTHIS, I'm not sure about it, maybe you're right. But you can add `if: :valid?` to the `after_validation` callback in that case

Comment: in my case on the after_validation method the first line I added is: return if errors.any?

Comment: @AntonDieterle ```if: :valid?``` after a ```after_validation``` callback would result in a ```stack level too deep``` error as it starts a new validation. Therfor, @Cris R's solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 10):

Old question, I know, but it still comes up first in search. I think this article has a solution:

[Rails, nested attributes and before_save callbacks](http://tamersalama.com/2011/11/10/rails-nested-attributes-and-before_save-callbacks/)

If I'm understanding that article correctly, the problem (as @AntonDieterle explains in his answer) is that the child callback isn't triggered because the parent isn't "dirty." This arcticle's solution is to "force" it to be dirty by calling `attr_name_will_change!` on a parent attribute that, in fact, does not change.  See [Active Model Dirty] in the Rails API[2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Anton's solution of using `after_validation` instead of `before_save` sounds simpler, but I wanted to put this out there an an alternative.

Comment: Always rewarding to see links to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: WayBackMachine to the rescue! Try http://web.archive.org/web/20150613004201/http://tamersalama.com/2011/11/10/rails-nested-attributes-and-before_save-callbacks